# Hyperref / Hpdftex failure to compile

Tags: hyperref

I have TeX Live installed (and all packages updated), but run into problems with the `hyperref` package when I run pdfTeX.  I can compile documents without using the `hyperref` package without problems.

The error message starts with the following:

```
* hyperref using default driver hpdftex *

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def:34: Undefined
control sequence.

l.34 \Hy@VersionCheck
                 {hpdftex.def}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

... and continues from there, with repeated errors regarding subsequent control sequences.  I've tried compiling without using other packages to eliminate potential conflicts, and still get the error message.  I get the error message for `article` or `beamer` document class.

Answer (score 1):

### Broken installation

`\Hy@VersionCheck` is defined in `hyperref.sty` of version 2010-10-19 v6.81s and later. The driver file of your error message log has version 2012/11/06 v6.83m.

The versions of the package file `hyperref.sty` and its driver files `*.def` **must** match. Check your `.log` file, where your `hyperref.sty` comes from and which version is has.

If the file is found as `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty` with an outdated version, then the installation is broken and needs to be fixed.

If the `.log` file shows a stray outdated `hyperref.sty`, which is found before the correct `hyperref.sty`, then you have move (or delete) the outdated file away.

### Wrong loading

The driver file `hpdftex.def` is supposed to be loaded by `hyperref`.
There is no option `hpdftex`, therefore it must not be used as option for other packages such as `inputenc` (wrong: `\usepackage[hpdftex]{inputenc}`) and should not be loaded on its own (wrong: `\input{hpdftex.def}`).