# hyperref update April 2016 breaks latex, pdflatex, xelatex

Tags: hyperref

The change to the date in hyperref.sty breaks latex, pdflatex, xelatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

complains (with xelatex)

! Package hyperref Error: Version mismatch!

(hyperref)                * 2016/04/19 v6.83m3: hyperref.sty

(hyperref)                * 2012/11/06 v6.83m: hxetex.def.

I can't figure out where the bug report should be sent---apparently the LaTeX3 Team made the update---so I'm sending it here.

George Pigman

Comment: This change is in the TeX Live _pretest_ only and is already being addressed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report about an issue that has since been fixed

Comment: Im confused. To a newbie like myself, this issue is within in the scope defined on the help center page. Granted, it's not a question and so would need to be edited.  In any case @egreg could you point those of us still having this same issue to the solution/fix?  I know this is old, but I am having this same problem with pdflatex.

Comment: @Caddisfly This is not a site for posting bug reports to. Did you update your TeX distribution?

Comment: @egreg thank you for clarifying that point.  Yes I updated MikTeX (twice actually just to make sure).

Comment: Please, open a new question with all the details.

Comment: Actually this question helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237971/hyperref-hpdftex-failure-to-compile#237982    I found a stray hyperref.sty file on our server and replaced it with the newest version which solved the problem.

Comment: I will say that, I'm not certain I would know the difference between a bug that needed to be filed with the package developer vs. a coding issue which could be asked here.  The help page implies that posting about a bug is OK, (provided the poster does some checking first) but the comments here make me feel like it isnt OK.  I'm guessing new users/posters would have the same confusion.